# .nextLine() jumps straight to next output

Tags: java, string, netbeans, input, system

I am on an Java encryption program where it prompts user to map his/her own String sequence from A-Z, 0-9, full stop, comma, exclamation mark and Space.

The programs runs like this:

User enter a String of different sequence from this:

```
String original= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.,!";
String example= "!,.1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
```

User will now choose to encrypt his own String.

```
Example output: 

Text to Encrypt: ENCRYPT
Encrypted Text: 2Q.TSEU
```

User can also choose to decrypt a String.

```
Text to Decrypt: 2Q.TSEU
Decrypted Text: ENCRYPT
```

However, I am unable to take in `Space` input for user's preferred String to encrypt.

I tried using `.nextLine()`instead of `.next()` but I met some bugs.

---

When I use String `textToEncrypt= sc.nextLine();`
this is the output I get.

```
Text to Encrypt: Encrypted Text: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
(1-Encrypt) (2-Decrypt) (3-Quit):
```

Instead of allowing user to enter the text, it jumps to the next line immediately and goes back to the `while` loop which asks for user's choice.

Comment: It would really help if you could post a short but *complete* program (with proper indentation) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Strings next() and nextLine() Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873351/reading-strings-next-and-nextline-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextLine` in all places :

```
while (run) {
  System.out.print("(1-Encrypt) (2-Decrypt) (3-Quit): ");
                option = sc.nextLine().charAt(0); // here
  if (option == '1') {

    System.out.print("\nText to Encrypt: ");
    String userEncrypt = sc.nextLine(); // and here
    ...
```